# Analytics Facet issue - Syntax Error after token ) :: ilter q by (());

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, facet

I have a SAQL step in my dashboard that goes something like this:

```
q = load "aDataset";
q = filter q by 'A__c' == "true" && !('B__c' >= "-");
q = filter q by 'Type__c' != "Organization";

q_A = filter q by 'x.CEmail__c' == "true";
q_B = filter q by 'x.CLetter__c' == "true";
q_C = filter q by 'x.CPhone_Joined' == "true";
q_D = filter q by 'x.CSMS__c' == "true";
q_F = filter q by 'y.CEmail__c' == "true";
q_G = filter q by 'y.CLetter__c' == "true";
q_H = filter q by 'y.CPhone_Joined' == "true";
q_I = filter q by 'y.CSMS__c' == "true";

result = group q_A by all full, q_B by all full, q_C by all full, q_D by all full, q by all full, q_F by all full, q_G by all full, q_H by all full, q_I by all;

result_A = foreach result generate "Email" as 'Typ', count(q_A) as 'X', count(q_F) as 'Y';
result_B = foreach result generate "Letter" as 'Typ' , count(q_B) as 'X', count(q_G) as 'Y';
result_C = foreach result generate "Phone" as 'Typ' , count(q_C) as 'X', count(q_H) as 'Y';
result_D = foreach result generate "SMS" as 'Typ', count(q_D) as 'X', count(q_I) as 'Y';

result_All = union result_A,result_B,result_C,result_D;
```

That produces a chart like below:
[image]

The problem starts when I click on any bar inside the above chart. The facet is applied and all other widgets (steps) in the same dashboard throw an error similar to this one:

> This widget can't be displayed because there is a problem with its source step:
>
> Syntax Error at position [line 1: column 443] after token ) :: ilter q by (()); q_B = filte

What am I doing wrong?

I don't know how to debug this since I cannot see the resulting query that is failing.

I'm assuming that the empty brackets in `ilter q by (());` from the error message is the issue, and that these brackets shouldn't be empty, which probably means that my `foreach` statements in SAQL is missing something, but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 0):

make sure
1- the datasets still valid and  available there as sometimes it's corrupted because of invalid entry or when  dataflow is run 
2- there should be no null value in datasets
3- trying refresh it and if not get still fix then simply create it once again i am sure it is gonna  work. as it happen because Einstein analytics is not yet stable